# Using a vector as a variable in a formula

Tags: r

I've got a function which acts on several columns, but I'd like to adapt it to use a different value of the main variable, `mode`, for each column. I have put a simplified example below.

My data is a cross tabulation of frequency i.e. in column A01 there are 6485 counts of 13 CAGs, 35 counts of 14 CAGs etc. The modal value for column 1 is therefore 13.

I need to calculate:
1) Skewness using (mean - mode)/sd
2) Proportion of each column where CAG is > than the mode

The code below works for that. 
However, I now need to compare each sample to the mode of a control sample and I'm a bit stuck with the code. The sample against which each needs to be compared is defined in the table `controls`.
 Could I please ask for help adapting my code so that skewmode and prop are calculated using the appropriate control mode for each column?
 I hope that makes sense!

```
#Data set
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15, 17), 
                   A01 = c(6485,35,132, 12), 
                   A02 = c(0,42,56, 4))

#Mode
mode <- data[sapply(data[2:ncol(data)], which.max), ]$CAG 

#Summary statistics
sumstats <- sapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  data_e <- rep(data$CAG, x)
  library(psych)
  data.frame(
    describe(data_e)
  )
})

sumstats <- as.data.frame(t(sumstats))

sumstats[] <- lapply(sumstats, function(x) {
  as.numeric(x)
})

# Results table
results <- data.frame(mode, sumstats)

# Skewness - I'd like to replace 'results$mode' here 
# with the relevant mode from the controls table
skewmode <- (results$mean - results$mode) / results$sd

# Proportion > mode I'd like to replace 'mod' here 
# with the relevant mode from the controls table
prop <- lapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  mod <- data$CAG[which.max(x)]
  B <- sum(x[data$CAG >= mod])
  A <- sum(x[data$CAG <= mod])
  B/(A+B)
})

prop <- as.data.frame(prop)
prop <- t(prop)

results <- data.frame(mode, sumstats, skewmode, prop)

# Controls
ctrls <- data.frame(samples = c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'), 
                    ctrl = c('A01','A01', 'A03', 'A03'))
```

Comment: I see where you want controls mode to be replaced. How is samples mode used?

Comment: In skewmode I want to use to look up the sample name from 'results' to look in 'ctrls' for which sample it should be comparing against, then use that sample to look up in 'mode' for the mode of that sample. I'd like to use that value instead of 'results$mode' in the 'skewmode' calculation.

Comment: Regarding 'prop'. Each column in 'data' represents a sample, and each sample has a control sample, defined in 'ctrls'. I'd like 'prop' to use the mode from the control sample rather than calculating mod

Comment: I understand where you want `cntrls$cntrl` mode to go as you comment in code. My question is how is `cntrls$samples` ever used? Is it to decide which column to use at very beginning in *data* including s/lapply inputs for *sumstats* and *prop*?

Comment: All the code above 'ctrls' is an example of functioning code  that I originally wrote. I added 'ctrls' to let you know which control to use for which sample e.g. For sample A02 we should use the mode of sample A01 (which is 13) in the skewmode and prop formulae

Comment: See my proposed solution. It's one of those hit or miss deals. Hopefully I understood your needs which is still a bit difficult to understand for me and maybe even to explain for you! Maybe adjust to actuals.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Map` (the wrapper to `mapply`) which passes both *sample mode* and *control mode* iteratively into a defined function, `prop_skew_calc()`, to calculate *skewmode* and *prop*. At the end, outputs a list of dataframes for final row bind.

NOTE: below demonstrates with base R's `summary()` since I do not have the *psyche* package. However, I leave a comment in code on how to integrate `psych::describe()` which [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf) indicate returns a dataframe of summary stats useful for psychometrics:

**Data** *(adding A03 and A04)*

```
#Data set
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15, 17), 
                   A01 = c(6485,35,132, 12), 
                   A02 = c(0,42,56, 4),
                   A03 = c(33,5014,2221, 18),
                   A04 = c(106,89,436, 11))

#Controls
ctrls <- data.frame(samples = c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'), 
                    ctrl = c('A01','A01', 'A03', 'A03'))
```

**Function** *(removes any l/sapply looping since scalar values will be passed iteratively by Map)*

```
library(psych)

prop_skew_calc <- function(x, y) {

  #Mode
  samplemode <- data$CAG[which.max(data[[x]])] 
  cntrlmode <- data$CAG[which.max(data[[y]])]

  #Summary statistics
  sumstats <- summary(rep(data$CAG, data[[x]]))     # R base's summary()
  sumstats <- as.data.frame(t(unclass(sumstats)))   

  #sumstats <- describe(rep(data$CAG, data[[x]]))   # pysche's describe()
  #sumstats <- as.data.frame(t(sumstats))           

  # Results table
  results <- data.frame(cntrlmode, sumstats)

  # Skewness
  skewmode <- (results$Mean - results$cntrlmode) / results$Min

  # Proportion
  B <- sum(data[data$CAG >= cntrlmode, x])
  A <- sum(data[data$CAG <= cntrlmode, x])
  prop <- B/(A+B)

  results <- data.frame(samplemode, cntrlmode, sumstats, skewmode, prop=prop)
}
```

**Map** *(calling above function, passing columns of ctrl dataframe)*

```
dfList <- Map(prop_skew_calc, ctrls$samples, ctrls$ctrl)

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
finaldf
#   samplemode cntrlmode Min. X1st.Qu. Median  Mean X3rd.Qu. Max.   skewmode        prop
# 1         17        17   13       14     15 14.90       17   17 -0.1615385 0.223684211
# 2         13        17   13       13     13 13.05       13   17 -0.3038462 0.001797484
# 3         15        13   14       14     15 14.67       15   17  0.1192857 1.000000000
# 4         14        13   13       14     14 14.31       15   17  0.1007692 0.995491187
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried applying it to my real data set and am unfortunately getting incorrect answers. I've commented above and included some of the read data

Comment: You are not running `psyche` package's `describe()` which you have installed but I don't and hence I use `summary()`. Please see note in this answer and commented out lines in code. This is why output columns differ. Plus you have two *skew* columns but your original post did not. You need to adjust this answer to fit your needs.